# Run Checkstyle before gradle build on build.gradle.kts and make build fail if there are issues

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, checkstyle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I added `Checkstyle` to my `Gradle` project's `build.gradle.kts` succesfully:

```
plugins {
    ...
    checkstyle
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "10.3.2"
    isIgnoreFailures = false // Added this so that the tasks fail if CheckStyle errors are present.
}
```

I now have access to CheckStyle's tools with:

- `gradle checkstyleMain`
- `gradle checkstyleTest`

They both work as expected showing warnings and generating HTML reports.

I now want to make the `gradle run` task run the `checkstyleMain` task before itself and to fail if there are CheckStyle issues.

Is there a way to do this? The only references I've found so far are not very clear and are for `Groovy` and `Android` instead of `Kotlin` and `Java` `build.gradle` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "10.3.2"
    isIgnoreFailures = false
    maxWarnings = 0
    maxErrors = 0
}

val build = "build"
tasks[build].dependsOn("checkstyleMain")
```

Now `gradle build` fails if there are errors found in `checkstyleMain` .

Comment: But where to put this exactly?

Answer (score 1):

To make task depends on another task you need to use [dependsOn](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:dependsOn(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)): 
`bootRun.dependsOn(checkstyleMain)`

For failing in case of `error/warning` it is possible to use following configuration for `checkstyle`:

```
ignoreFailures = false
maxWarnings = 0
maxErrors = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! For me ignoreFailures was causing a build error, so I changed to isIgnoreFailures

Comment: Also, for the dependsOn part, I don't have a bootRun task, so I am trying to attach this to the default build one. I tried run.dependsOn(checkstyleMain) , But I get Unresolved reference errors on both run and checkStyleMain . Where should this code go? Am I missing something?